# Not able to install package because pip is not installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am running Ubuntu and have both python 2.7 and python 3.5 on my system

I have tweaked the settings so that when I do

```
python test.py
```

python3 runs

I wanted to install the module pyperclip in python3..

```
pip install pyperclip
```

installed it for python 2

Quick google search suggested to use

```
pip3 install pyperclip
```

but I get

```
pip3 is currently not installed . You can install it by typing
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

When I run this command I get the following:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
python3-pip : Depends: python-pip-whl (= 8.1.1-2) but 8.1.1-   2ubuntu0.2 is to be installed
           Recommends: python3-dev (>= 3.2) but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: python3-setuptools but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: python3-wheel but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What should I do?

Comment: Did you try installing `python-pip-whl` as it said? Also, let me get this straight, `python` runs Python 3 but `pip` uses Python 2?

Comment: I have not tried installing it... How should I do it ....Yes ''python'' runs python3 I just changed in its setting that whenever I type python it actually means python 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like it could be an error in your path. If you installed Python 3.5 it should come with pip, so try doing `python -m pip` and this should run Python 3.5's pip. To install something, simply use the normal pip commands as you have, for example `python -m pip install pyperclip`.

Comment: It says: Could not import setuptools which is required to install from a source distribution.
Please install setuptools

Comment: Try `python -m pip install setuptools` and see if that works, then try the initial command again.

Comment: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/bin/easy_install'

Comment: Add `sudo` at the front of it and try it again.

Comment: Was able to do finally.....I had placed alias python=python3 in the ~/.bashrc file ..I removed it....Now I have to use python3 to make python run using python 3.5.2 but simple python3 -m pip install pyperclip did the job

Answer (score 1):

Use the `aptitude` package manager as it will provide you simple suggestion to fix your unmet dependencies problem. Install it via apt:

`sudo apt-get install aptitude`

Then install `pip3` with this command:

`sudo aptitude install python3-pip`

Then choose the solution suggested to you by `aptitude`. In one of the suggestions `aptitude` will suggest you to downgrade from 8.1.1-2ubuntu0.2 to 8.1.1-2. Accepting this suggestion solves the issue. Just make sure the downgrade doesn't cause you other hurdles.